# How to see a SQLite database content with Visual Studio Code

Tags: database, sqlite, pycharm, visual-studio-code

I'm new to `Django` and try to see a `SQLite3` file. 
I'm looking for a way to open and view a database content with `visual studio code` like Pycharm can do (see picture) [image: Database content view in Pycharm]

Does an extension could do that? Is it possible to achieve this in VSC?

Comment: the person who did this Visual Studio extension, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox may be willing to do a Visual Code one as well.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I published an extension to query and explore sqlite3 databases

[vscode-sqlite](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite)

Comment: I downloaded your extension, but nothing seems to happen when I try to open the database. I am new to this and created a toy database with db browser, but I haven't been able to create a "connection profile" as required by visual studio code. Could this be the problem as to why I am not able to run your extension?

Comment: Thanks for your Extension @Alex Covizzi ! I installed it, but if I open a very simple SQLite database, it just says `The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway?`. This is weird, I used to open sqlite3 db quite easily within vsc with an older version of vsc, even without any extension. But since I reinstalled, its somehow not allowing me to open databases, with or without extension. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @MJimitater You probably already figured it out, but to open the database you need to Right Click > Open Database.

Comment: @AlexCovizzi thank you. Well, if I do that, then I run into the message I wrote above.. really don't know how to open the database

Comment: I also needed this installation: `sudo apt install sqlite`

Answer (score 34):

1. Just install the sqlite extension in your visual studio code: [VSCode-SQLite](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite)
2. Then you can right-click on the database file and click "Open Database".
   [SQLite database in visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdLXX.png)
3. Expand the database.
   [expanded sqlite database in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7cPr.png)
4. Click the play button in front of each table to view table contents.
   [SQLite table in visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RziA1.png)

Comment: On my version the play button is to the right of each table and can be seen only if the table is highlighted/selected or hovered over. Otherwise good summary, as it was not obvious how to use this.

Comment: @Puya Fazlali thank you, your screenshots are helpful.

Answer (score 29):

For anyone that is still confused..

Follow the first 3 steps in Puya's answer, and at the very bottom of the Explorer panel there should be a tab called: `> SQLITE EXPLORER` (mine was minimised, even after clicking 'Open Database' - making it hard to notice)

In here, you should be able to see the contents of your database file.
You can then right click a table and 'Show Table':

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! I was looking all over for it. Right in front of my face but it's so far down in the explorer it's hard to see. I almost removed it. From reading reviews others are having a problem finding it. Look to the far left of your VSCose at the bottom. Just to the right of the gear icon.

Comment: And if you accidentally hide the view (like me), scroll down the View / Open View... menu dialog until you find SQLite Explorer view...

Answer (score 10):

Obviously, there is not yet a corresponding extension for vscode. Me, if necessary, I use "SQLite-Database-Browser". Very simple and sufficient for my purposes.

If you want to give it a try: [SQLite-Database-Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org)

By the way, using Django with another database, such as `PostgreSQL` or `MySQL`, is not too difficult.

Comment: Thanks for sharing "SQLite-Database-Browser". I use it too and it's very convenient and useful. But I was looking for something embedded inside vsc. Anyway I will wait for it. It could happen soon maybe.