# Visual studio code doesn't read db.sqlite3 in django framework

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I saw a tutorial of django on youtube. That tutorial explain that I must open and write the db.sqlite3 file. Unfortunately Visual Studio Code doesn't read that file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see a SQLite database content with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993895/how-to-see-a-sqlite-database-content-with-visual-studio-code)

Comment: unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit an db.sqlite3 file in Visual Studio Code you will need to install [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexcvzz.vscode-sqlite).

You can learn how to use sqlite together with Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/).